# How to remove .html from URL and redirect when the html will be accessed directly

Tags: html, .htaccess, file

I know that I can remove the .html using the remove html .htaccess code which is this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

I still don't like this cause when visitors access my site with a .html extension then the .html will still not be removed and can still be shown by the visitors.
But I want a user to be redirected without a .html extension when he/she access the file directly. For example when a visitor wants to access file1.html directly on the browser then it automatically redirects or delete the .html extension, so instead of showing file1.html when accessed directly on browser then it will automatically rewrite "file1.html" to "file1" without the html extension anymore.

Also additional, how to add a trailing slash?

(Truly sorry if I haven't elaborate clearly.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your .htaccess file try adding:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.html
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

should remove `.html` and add a trailing `/`

[source](https://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/)